# PublicClientApplication - AcquireTokenInteractive - Group Membership

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, .net-core-3.1

I am writing a .Net Core 3.1 WPF application that will authenticate against Azure Active Directory.  I have created the App Registration in Azure and my call to PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive is successful.

However, now, I want to add another layer of security - only users in a certain group can run the WPF application.  I have tried multiple approaches to this:

**Option 1:** I tried adding this code to my call to AcquireTokenInteractive.  I thought this would require that the user be in my group, but it did not force the call to fail.  I could find no documentation on how to format the claim string - maybe this will work if the claim string is formatted correctly.

```
var result = await App.AcquireTokenInteractive(new List<string> { Scope })
                    .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .WithClaims("<MY AD Group's Guid Id>")
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Option 2.** I also looked at trying to query the group membership after the successful call to AcquireTokenInteractive, but I am unsure of the best way to do this.

What is the best way to accomplish this - a .Net Core 3.1 WPF application authenticating against Azure AD and also confirming the user is in a specific group.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include Groups claim in your token as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes). You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

The token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below :

```
{
  "groups": ["{group id}"]
}
```

Then you can make logical judgments based on the group id in your code.

**Another method** is [adding an appRole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#declare-app-roles-using-azure-portal) into your Azure AD app and [assigning users and groups to roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles).

Then the users in the group will have the claim like below:

```
{
  "roles": ["{the role you customized}"]
}
```

Then you can implement your authorization logic based on the roles of the user.

Comment: It might also be possible to require user assignment on the app, and then assign the group to an appRole like you said right?

Comment: Though of course that role check still needs to be done in the back-end

Comment: OK - I did as you suggested and added "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup".  However, the result from calling AcquireTokenInteractive is an object of type Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult.  There is no place that I can see in that object that shows the group memberships.  So even if the server returns the data, how do I read it?

Comment: OK - also tried your role idea, but couldn't get it to work.  I added the role to the manifest and it shows as a role when adding users to the enterprise application.  I did not add my user to the rule, but I did add this code to my calling application:
    .WithClaims("{\"roles\": \"<Guid id of role>\"]}")

and also tried this
    .WithClaims("{\"roles\": \"<name of role>\"]}")

Even though my user was not in the role, AcquireTokenInteractive allowed me to log in which is what I am trying to prevent.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Steve0212 `AcquireTokenInteractive` is for getting tokens. It will validate some aspects of the ID token, but it will not make any authorization decisions based off of  group or role claims (or lack thereof). The `WithClaims(...)` method is not used for this, it's used for a different scenario ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/conditional-access-dev-guide), if you're curious).

Comment: Thanks Philippe - so after I call ```AcquireTokenInteractive``` to get a token, what do I call / do to check roles or group membership?

Comment: Ah, I think I found it.  I added this code ```var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(result.AccessToken);``` and in the claims I can see groups and roles.  Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: @Steve0212 Sorry for the delay. Yes. you need to get the token. It seems that you have got the group id and role claims. Anything else we can help with?